# Why do we use less-than-or-equals (<=) symbol in semaphores?

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, semaphore

While implementing the waiting code in a semaphore we use the following code:

```
wait(semaphore s) { while(s<=0); s -= 1;}
```

Instead we can use:

```
wait(semaphore s) { while(s==0); s -= 1;}
```

The result will be same. Then why do most of all prefer using the first one?

Comment: I suggest that you do not use either since they are both hopeless CPU loops.

Answer (score 1):

A (counting) semaphore may be initialized with a negative value, for example to have a single thread wait until 5 other threads arrive at a specific point:

```
shared:
  semaphore with counter initialised to -4

waiter thread:
  wait(semaphore)
  print "Done waiting"

other threads:
  incredible important work
  post(semaphore)
```

Therefore, you need to also check for negative counter values.